# Calculate time execution for different methods

Tags: java, oop, time

I have something like this:

```
in main()
getinitialtime()
create object(constructor generates random values)

method1 does something with that object's class members, let's say addition of 2 numbers
gettime1()
method2 does something else with those members, let's say substraction
gettime2()
```

I want to calculate the time that `method1` and `method2` use sepparately. But I can't because declaring another object would change the class members since they are randomly generated. I know I can just calculate `gettime2-getinitialtime-gettime1` and `gettime1-getinitialtime`, but isn't there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three possible solutions:

1. If you generate the internal properties randomly with `java.util.Random` and using the same `seed` (but two different `Random` objects), then the generated sequences will be identical, and so the objects.
2. You can provide some method to copy the values from one object to the other, or just override `clone()` and create a clone of the first object.
3. You can provide another constructor that takes the values from the outside, so you can generate them as you wish and inject them into the two objects.